# Converting a list to `IO (IOArray Int a)` in Haskell

Tags: arrays, haskell, types, io

I need to write a function that takes a list of `a` and returns `IO (IOArray Int a)`

```
listToArray :: [a] -> IO (IOArray Int a)
```

I need some help to get started with `IO` arrays. I create a new one by  `newListArray`  but then it seems that I have to commit to a specific type and my function needs to work with any type `a`.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to work with any type you can take a look at this type signature

```
newListArray :: (MArray a e m, Ix i) => (i, i) -> [e] -> m (a i e)
```

where the `m` is `IO`, `a` is `IOArray` and `i` is `Int`.

This one requires start and end index of the array. You can see in detail here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Array-MArray.html#v:newListArray

Comment: Thanks! now I have the code compiling . BTW how do I display the content of my IOArray ?

Comment: @GilShafriri You can probably use this `getElems`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Array-MArray.html#v:getElems

I suggest learning to navigate around hackage, when you are used to it, you will be able to know which function to use.

Comment: The problem is that they don'y give any example. I realized that I have to convert my IO (IOArray Int a) type into  (IOArray Int a) type using the  <-  operator in order to use  getElems.

Comment: @GilShafriri you don't *"convert"* an `IO (IOArray Int a)` type value into an `IOArray Int a` type value; you *"draw / get hold on"* an `IOArray Int a` type value *from* the I/O computation denoted by the `IO (IOArray Int a)` type value. When that computation will run, your `arr` variable, say, in the `arr <- ...` line, will get bound to the actual pure value of type `IOArray Int a` produced / computed / by that impure I/O computation.

Comment: @GilShafriri Or you can stop torturing yourself with this terrible interface of `array` package and use something like `vector` or `massiv`

Comment: This is hw assignment and he likes to torture the  students :)